# HTTP Live Streaming -Play from Bundle

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Similar questions have been asked before, but I could never find a solution.

I am trying to play a m3u8 file from bundle . I have streamed it successfully over http .but i really need to play movie from bundle and wanted to use http live streaming .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Download the file & save**

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/playlist.m3u8"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *the_file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if(err != nil) {
    // do some error handling, e.g. NSLog(@"Fail: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
} else {
    // save the file ( see Step 2 )
}
```

**Step 2 : Save the file**

You can either save it as file, or save it as an object .

// save as file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/playlist.m3u8", docDirectory];
[the_file writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

// OR, save as object
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:the_file forKey:@"MY_M3U8"];
```

**Step 3 : Read the file**

```
// read from file 
NSString *textPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playlist.m3u8"];
// the FILE is loaded


// OR, read from object
NSString *content = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"MY_M3U8"];
// it will contain the CONTENT of file
```

**Step 4 : Play it in your player**